# REGEXP_SUBSTR to update a table

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I am trying to use `REGEXP_SUBSTR` to update a column in a table and I am getting the error, missing expression.

```
UPDATE p_table SET f_name = SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR ( (SELECT user_name
                          FROM user_info
                         WHERE ROWID = R_ID ('user_info')), '[^ ]{1,15}', 1, 1)
            FROM DUAL;
```

When I add parentheses before the first select and after dual it works but sets all the rows in that column to the same value.  I do not need them all to be unique but I cannot have them all the same.  Thanks for any advice you could give me.

```
UPDATE p_table SET f_name = (SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR ( (SELECT user_name
                          FROM user_info
                         WHERE ROWID = R_ID ('user_info')), '[^ ]{1,15}', 1, 1) 
            FROM DUAL);
```

Comment: It's the "," after the "1" on the 2nd last line. It's expecting something else to follow...

Comment: Your expression seems to be missing a bit, but I guess that was lost when you copied across. Your subquery doesn't seem to be correlated with the table you're updating; the subquery will generate a single value (I think) so all rows will be set to the same value. How do you want values to be generated - what's the link between the two tables?

Comment: Thanks for catching that.  I updated the statements above.

Comment: R_ID is a function the selects a random row.  From that random row in the user_info table, it uses the first name and inserts it into f_name.

Comment: When I run the statement below I get a random value.              SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR ( (SELECT user_name
                          FROM user_info
                         WHERE ROWID = R_ID ('user_info')), '[^ ]{1,15}', 1, 1) 
            FROM DUAL;

Comment: In case you're looking to get a random name for every row being updated, please read this about calling functions from SQL: http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:3181424400346795479

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in @PatrickMarchand comment Oracle optimizes query, so your function called only once. [AskTom article](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:3181424400346795479) makes it clear.

To get a workaround you must introduce something linked to p_table rows into function parameters to force Oracle call it for every row. 
For example `rowid` from `p_table`:

```
UPDATE p_table 
SET f_name = (
      SELECT 
        REGEXP_SUBSTR( 
          ( SELECT user_name FROM user_info
            WHERE ROWID = R_ID ('user_info', p_table.rowid)
          ), 
          '[^ ]{1,15}', 1, 1
        ) 
      FROM DUAL
    )
```

[SQLFiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5c39b/1).

Comment: Thanks for your help.  SQLFiddle and the AskTom was a lot of help.

Answer (score 0):

Does it do what you want without the subquery?

```
UPDATE p_table
    SET f_name = (SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(user_name, '[^ ]{1,15}', 1, 1)
                  FROM user_info
                  WHERE ROWID = R_ID ('user_info')
                 );
```

Comment: No it just updates all the rows with the same value.  I need the rows to be mostly different.  Thanks for your help.